# Counterexamples: $x$ ad-semisimple $\implies$ $\mathfrak g$-action of $x$ semisimple?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples

**Context**
Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra over a field $k$.
We call an element $x \in \mathfrak g$ *ad-semisimple* if $ad_x \in \mathfrak gl(\mathfrak g)$ is a semisimple endomorphism.
Similarly, we call an element $x \in \mathfrak g$ *ad-nilpotent* if $ad_x \in \mathfrak gl(\mathfrak g)$ is a nilpotent endomorphism.

In the following let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra and $\rho: \mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak gl(V)$ a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak g$-representation. One can show that if $x \in \mathfrak g$ is ad-semisimple then $\rho (x)$ is semisimple (equivalently diagonalizable since we consider $\mathbb C$-vector spaces). Similarly, $x \in \mathfrak g$ ad-nilpotent implies that $\rho (x)$ is nilpotent. This follows from the fact that given the unique absolute Jordan decomposition (also known as the additive Jordan-Chevalley decomposition) $x=s+n$ (which exists in any complex semisimple Lie algebra) the Jordan decomposition of $\rho (x)$ is given by $\rho(x)=\rho(s)+\rho(n)$.

**Questions**

- Do these two implications ($x$ ad-semisimple/ad-nilpotent implies $\rho (x)$ semisimple/nilpotent) fail when $\mathfrak g$ is not a complex semisimple Lie algebra?
- If so, what are counterexamples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: If $L$ is any non-perfect, finite dimensional Lie algebra (over a field $k$), the natural map $L \rightarrow L/[L,L]$ is a surjection from $L$ to a finite dimensional abelian Lie algebra.

Hint 2: a) The diagonal matrices inside $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ form an $n$-dimensional abelian Lie algebra, all of whose nonzero elements are not nilpotent as matrices.

b) The matrices of the form $\pmatrix{0 &* &*&*&\dots&*\\ 0&0&0&0&...&0\\\vdots&&&\ddots &&\vdots}$ inside $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ form an $(n-1)$-dimensional abelian Lie algebra, all of whose nonzero elements are not semisimple as matrices.

Can you combine the hints to find, for any (finite-dim.) non-perfect Lie algebra (over an arbitrary field $k$), a representation $\rho$ such that some $ad$-nilpotent element $x \in L$ is sent to a non-nilpotent matrix $\rho(x)$, and/or some $ad$-semisimple element is sent to a non-semisimple matrix?

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. Do you mean "If $L$ is not *perfect* (if $L$ is at least one-dimensional this follows from the nilpotency of $L$) […]“ instead of "if $L$ is not abelian" in your first hint? Regarding your hints: Any linear map between abelian Lie algebras is a Lie algebra morphism. Hence, any n-dimensional abelian Lie algebra is isomorphic (as a Lie algebra) to the diagonal matrices $\mathfrak h(n,k) \subset \mathfrak gl_n(k)$. Let $L$ be any finite-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra. Suppose $L/[L,L]$ is $n$-dimensional …

Comment: Consider a Lie algebra iso $f:L/[L,L] \rightarrow \mathfrak h(n,k)$. Then $\rho: L \xrightarrow{\pi}L/[L,L] \xrightarrow{f} \mathfrak h(n,k) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak gl_n(k)$ gives us a non-trivial representation of $L$ where $\rho(x)$ is not nilpotent for every $x \in L$ (since $f \circ \pi$ is surjective).

Comment: Here we assume that $L$ is at least one-dimensional. As an example one could consider as $L$ the strictly-upper triangular $(mxm)$-matrices. The above example fails for semisimple Lie algebras $L$ since they are perfect. Regarding your last hint: One can consider the abelian matrix Lie algebra of diagonal $(mxm)$-matrices (with commutator). Except for the zero matrix no element in this matrix Lie algebra is nilpotent…

Comment: … as for abelian matrix Lie algebras where (except for the zero matrix) no element is diagonalizable I can only think of one-dimensional examples. What are others? Are my thoughts what you were hinting at?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. I have streamlined and shortened things, and added an example of an abelian matrix LA of arbitrary finite dimension, all of whose nonzero elements are not diagonalisable. Note that even if you just knew a one-dimensional example for that, you would still be done, because after you are down to an abelian Lie algebra, you can just project that to one of its basis vectors and get a one-dimensional abelian Lie algebra.